# What is a frozen post?

Tags: support, locked-posts, historical-lock

Recently I tried commenting on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743069/visual-studio-exit-without-exception-or-return), but the comment couldn't be added. The message told me that the question was either locked, deleted, or frozen.

At the time, I tried to add the comment, the question was on hold, but still visible to me. As it was neither locked nor deleted, this would appear to have been a frozen question (the third possibility mentioned in the error message). So what does "frozen" mean in this context?

Comment: Do you still have a link to that post (in your browser history maybe)?

Comment: When you say it was not locked or deleted, are you 100% positive that it wasn't deleted at that exact moment?  I mean, there are plenty of times that I have tried to comment on a post to have it deleted while I was in the middle of writing the comment.  I can still see the post because it wasn't deleted when I started looking at it, but it was deleted by the time I tried to hit "add comment".

Comment: @psubsee2003 yes , I'm sure because it was still there for a moment after trying to comment

Comment: @Mat sorry, didn't find it in my browser's history

Comment: @Mat I found the url , but how will you open the question ? it's deleted . [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743069/visual-studio-exit-without-exception-or-return)

Comment: @niceman how long is "a moment".  If it was very brief (meaning a few seconds), you could have still been looking at a cached version before the server caught up to the change in state and removed it from view.  For the record, there is no specific "Frozen" state.  There is various versions of locked posts (that lock different parts of the post), and there is deleted.

Comment: @niceman, high-rep users (10k+) can view deleted posts.

Comment: When a post is Frozen, you should just let it go. Let it go...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The term "frozen" only applies to historical lock situations. Under normal circumstances, locking a question does not subsequently lock or prevent any action on the answers under that question.

This situation is different for one particular lock: the historical lock. When used, the question *and* all its answers become "frozen in time," completely removing most of the options to interact with the posts from the page. Since the answers below the question are not *themselves* locked in the technical sense of the word, you might instead consider them frozen.

From the FAQ on the uber-Meta [*Historically locking a post ends the debate over whether a question should be kept on the site or deleted*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631/158100)

Comment: "historical lock situations" but the question was new, I found it in the newest tab of Unanswered questions

Comment: @niceman I'm only answering what the term frozen means. You've already solved the problem in the comments that the question was deleted, which is why you received that message. Sometimes things happen to a post while you're viewing it, that's just the nature of the Internet.

Comment: anyway, by historical, you mean a question which was locked and then unlocked, can the locked questions be unlocked ?

Comment: @niceman A historical lock is the name of one of the locks, as [demonstrated on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c).

Comment: @animuson Then would it be possible to remove that word from the error message? I got that recently and I too wondered what a frozen post was.